# Deeplearning4j Error: no jniopenblas in java.library.path

Tags: java, deeplearning4j, dl4j

I first started using Deeplearning4j this weekend. I looked at the page at https://deeplearning4j.org/docs/latest/deeplearning4j-quickstart and saw the option for "Eclipse setup without Maven". Since I was used to using Eclipse and had never heard of Maven before, I decided to follow those instructions.

After I set it up, I found a tutorial on YouTube but when I go to run the project, I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jniopenblas in java.library.path
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.loadLibrary(Loader.java:945)
at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:750)
at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:657)
at org.bytedeco.javacpp.openblas.<clinit>(openblas.java:10)
at org.nd4j.linalg.cpu.nativecpu.blas.CpuBlas.setMaxThreads(CpuBlas.java:87)
at org.nd4j.nativeblas.Nd4jBlas.<init>(Nd4jBlas.java:36)
at org.nd4j.linalg.cpu.nativecpu.blas.CpuBlas.<init>(CpuBlas.java:11)
at org.nd4j.linalg.cpu.nativecpu.CpuNDArrayFactory.createBlas(CpuNDArrayFactory.java:79)
at org.nd4j.linalg.factory.BaseNDArrayFactory.blas(BaseNDArrayFactory.java:71)
at org.nd4j.linalg.cpu.nativecpu.blas.CpuLevel3.<init>(CpuLevel3.java:26)
at org.nd4j.linalg.cpu.nativecpu.CpuNDArrayFactory.createLevel3(CpuNDArrayFactory.java:94)
at org.nd4j.linalg.factory.BaseNDArrayFactory.level3(BaseNDArrayFactory.java:92)
at org.nd4j.linalg.factory.BaseBlasWrapper.level3(BaseBlasWrapper.java:42)
at org.nd4j.linalg.api.ndarray.BaseNDArray.mmuli(BaseNDArray.java:2849)
at org.nd4j.linalg.api.ndarray.BaseNDArray.mmul(BaseNDArray.java:2643)
at org.deeplearning4j.nn.layers.BaseLayer.preOutput(BaseLayer.java:373)
at org.deeplearning4j.nn.layers.BaseLayer.activate(BaseLayer.java:384)
at org.deeplearning4j.nn.layers.BaseLayer.activate(BaseLayer.java:405)
at org.deeplearning4j.nn.multilayer.MultiLayerNetwork.activationFromPrevLayer(MultiLayerNetwork.java:590)
at org.deeplearning4j.nn.multilayer.MultiLayerNetwork.feedForwardToLayer(MultiLayerNetwork.java:713)
at org.deeplearning4j.nn.multilayer.MultiLayerNetwork.computeGradientAndScore(MultiLayerNetwork.java:1821)
at org.deeplearning4j.optimize.solvers.BaseOptimizer.gradientAndScore(BaseOptimizer.java:151)
at org.deeplearning4j.optimize.solvers.StochasticGradientDescent.optimize(StochasticGradientDescent.java:54)
at org.deeplearning4j.optimize.Solver.optimize(Solver.java:51)
at org.deeplearning4j.nn.multilayer.MultiLayerNetwork.fit(MultiLayerNetwork.java:1031)
at Tester.main(Tester.java:96)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no openblas in java.library.path
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.loadLibrary(Loader.java:945)
at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:738)
... 24 more
```

Comment: What does your classpath look like? Did you download all the archives needed?

Comment: All the steps mentions are worth to try, just do step by step and it's not that difficult to follow. It will work fine, maven is just build tool and should not worry about.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing the .dll (Windows) or .so (Linux) files that are needed for Deeplearning4J to function. You can fix it by downloading them and adding them to your classpath. This can be done in eclipse by selecting your project, clicking `Build path`, clicking `Configure build bath`, clicking `Source`, and changing `Native library location` to the folder where the .dll or .so files were downloaded to.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'm on Windows. Where do I download the .dll from?

Comment: You need the `openblas` dll which can be downloaded from https://sourceforge.net/projects/openblas/files/

Comment: I downloaded it, but now it's telling me I need to install it and that I need MinGW. Am I on the right track?